# Function to check if number (mod 2) has remainder of 0 doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm trying to make a simple program to check if the user inputed number has a remainder of 0.

```
foundN=input("Enter number: ")

def test(foundN):
    if foundN%2 == 0:
        print "The number ", foundN, "is ok."
    else:
        print "Try another number. "
```

When I input the number, it doesn't output anything. Also, when I make another command it executes it, just skipping the function test. Could anyone tell me why? 
Am I not importing the number to the foundN variable right or something else?

I've tried inputting the number like this: `foundN=int(raw_input('..'))`. It didn't help.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't called the function!

```
def test(foundN):
    if foundN%2 == 0:
        print "The number ", foundN, "is ok."
    else:
        print "Try another number. "

foundN = input("Enter number: ")
test(foundN)
```